# jQuery $('.class').is(":hover") needs a timeout in Firefox to return true

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js, settimeout, jquery-hover

I have a mouseout event set up for an svg circle.

On that mouseout, some tests are made to see if a tooltip or a background layer are hovered. If they hover there, the tip stays up; if they don't it's taken away.

The tip has a div (without a background) that extends to the area surrounding the circle. The code is:

```
                var isHoveredTip = $('.tipcontainer').is(":hover");
                var isHoveredOverlay = $('.mouseOverlay').is(":hover");

                //test if the user is mousing over the tip area
                if (isHoveredOverlay == true || isHoveredTip == true) {

                   //if the user is hovering the tip, take away the tip once they leave the tip area
                  $(".tipcontainer").on('mouseleave',function() {
                    d3.select(that).attr("r",(pointRadius) + "px");
                    tooltip.style("visibility","hidden").style("transition","visibility .0s linear .0s,opacity 0s linear");
                    d3.selectAll(".tipChart").remove();
                  });
                }
                 // take away the tip if they're not hovering
                else {

                  d3.select(that).attr("r",(pointRadius) + "px");
                  tooltip.style("visibility","hidden").style("transition","visibility .15s linear .15s,opacity 0s linear");
                  d3.selectAll(".tipChart").transition().duration(300).remove();
                }
```

Everything is gravy in Chrome. Firefox is giving me problems. The `isHoveredTip` and `isHoveredOverlay` variables only return true if I set a timeout for a few millisecond. It's as if the elements are not rendered on the mouseout of the circle. If I do set that time out, it creates collateral problems, where the code needs conditionals for whether other circles are moused over, which creates a code chain.

How can I get Firefox to register the hover event without a timeout?

Comment: Is it not necessary to mix d3 and jQuery.

Comment: Don't agree with you. They serve different use cases.

Comment: @In_code_veritas: You are absolutely right! Therefore, you should create d3 based class/library. The mix of different libraries calls increase amount of mistakes dramatically!

Comment: It depends on the project scope and needs. But thanks for your input it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `d3.mouse(this)` and just testing whether the mouse moved in the direction of the tooltip (the negative y direction). jQuery and svg do not play so nice with hover events.

```
              var coordinates = [0, 0];
              coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
              var x = coordinates[0];
              var y = coordinates[1];

              var testTip = function () {

                if (coordinates[1] < 0) { 
                    // do stuff
             }}
```

This seems like a much more D3 way to handle this problem anyway.